Why couldn't/wouldn't Scholz just block the EU tariffs on Chinese cars?
According to Euronews, in a speech in the Bundestag, Scholz criticized the (recently adopted) EU tariffs on Chinese electric cars.
Why just criticize though? Couldn't Germany have blocked those tariffs in the first place?

Isn't the point of the EU to have standard rules on things like imports?

@JoeW: and how are those adopted?

Simply vetoing something in the EU means spending accumulated political capital. One needs to decide if it's worth to do it. Or he doesn't really mean it that strongly.

By resolutions passed by representatives that each country sends to the EU?
